# Assigning multiple styles (sld from geoserver) in openlayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Hi this is my code I want to add a backend layer osm and the tiled and untiled wms layer with external sld files fetching the styles from geoserver. Please correct me. The styles when clicked is not changing with the user selection with the addition of the backend osm layer. so I want the osm layers with  the changing styles on wms layers.

```
layer:
<script>
var untiled = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      ratio: 1,
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wg/wms',
      params: {'FORMAT': format,
               'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
            STYLES: '',
            LAYERS: 'wg:UKNEWPANESR2015',
      }
    })
  });
  var tiled = new ol.layer.Tile({
    visible: false,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wg/wms',
      params: {'FORMAT': format, 
               'VERSION': '1.1.1',
               tiled: true,
            STYLES: '',
            LAYERS: 'wg:UKNEWPANESR2015',
      }
    })
  });
  //Openstreetmap layer
  var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
  }); 
osm.set('name', 'OSM');

var map = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
      attribution: false
    }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
    target: 'map',
    layers: [ osm,
      untiled,
      tiled  
    ]
 });

//Function to call styles
function setStyle(style){
    map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
      lyr.getSource().updateParams({'STYLES': style});
    });
  }
<script>
<body>
<div id="toolbar" style="display: none;">
  <ul><li>
      <a>Styles:</a>
      <select id="imageFormatSelector" onchange="setStyle(value)">
        <option value="">Default</option>
           <option value="BIOMASSGG-WEI">BIOMASSGG-WEI</option>  
           <option value="AGRO-WEIGHT">AGRO-WEIGHT</option>  
           <option value="BIOMASSGG">BIOMASSGG</option>  
           <option value="BIOENERGYSD">BIOENERGYSD</option>  
           <option value="BIOENERGYSD-WEIsld">BIOENERGYSD-   WEIsld</option>  
           <option value="AGROCLIMATICZONE">AGROCLIMATICZONE</option>  
      </select>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```